# How to calculate MySQL Query Memory/CPU Cost

Tags: mysql, memory, cpu-usage

Is there a way/tool/technique to calculate the processor and memory cost of a specific MySQL query?

Comment: You might want to mention whether you've already used `explain` or not, and if so, what you find lacking about it. It may not give what you want, but if you haven't tried it, it's usually the first thing to try.

Answer (score 3):

Check this sample:

[sample at mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-profiles.html)

Comment: Same page states that
> MEMORY is not currently implemented

I need a way to profile memory cost as well as the cpu.

Comment: SHOW PROFILES is deprecated, you can get better data with modern versions of MySQL using performance schema http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema.html